# File is not uploading to server in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

HI I am trying to upload a file with other form data where i have some name Email and phone number fields, All the other details are saving but image is not uploading, If i use postman i am able to upload image also with other details. Below is my code
On Handle Change:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFile(event.target.files[0]);
    
  };
```

On submit Button:

```
 const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(file)
    if (isAddMode) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append(
        "Upload",
        file,
        file.name
      );
      formData.append("Name", data.Name);
      formData.append("Email", data.Email);
      formData.append("Mobile", data.Mobile);
      formData.append("StartdateofExclusivity", data.StartdateofExclusivity);
      formData.append("AddressLine1", data.AddressLine1);
      formData.append("AddressLine2", data.AddressLine2);
      formData.append("City", data.City);
      formData.append("State", data.State);
      formData.append("Country", data.Country);
      formData.append("Zipcode", data.Zipcode);
      formData.append("Availability", data.Availability);
      formData.append("Qualification", data.Qualification);
      formData.append("Experience", data.Experience);
      formData.append("Jobtype", data.Jobtype);
      formData.append("Role", data.Role);
     const saveCandInfo = await saveCandidate(formData);
      if (saveCandInfo?.data?.status === "successfully created") {
        navigate("/candidates");
      }
    } else {
      const editCandidate = await updateCandidate(id, data);
      if (editCandidate?.data?.status === "success") {
        navigate("/candidates");
      }
    }
    
  };
```

And in service :

```
 export const saveCandidate = async (data) => {
      console.log(data)
        try {
          const saveCandidate = await axios.post(`${url}/hhc/createCandidate`, data, {headers:{"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}});
          return saveCandidate;
        } catch (error) {}
      };
```

JSX:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="contact-border">
          <div className="mb-1">
            <div className="d-flex flex-row my-2">
              <div className="col-md-3 form-floating">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="floatingInputValue"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  name="Name"
                  {...register("Name", { required: true })}
                />
                <label for="floatingInputValue">
                  Name<span className="mandatory">*</span>
                </label>
                {errors.Name?.type === "required" && (
                  <p role="alert" className="mandatory">
                    Name is required
                  </p>
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3 mx-3 form-floating">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="floatingInputValue"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  {...register("Email", { required: true })}
                />
                <label for="floatingInputValue">
                  Email<span className="mandatory">*</span>
                </label>
                {errors.Name?.type === "required" && (
                  <p role="alert" className="mandatory">
                    Email is required
                  </p>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="d-flex flex-row my-2">
              <div className="col-md-3 form-floating">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="floatingInputValue"
                  placeholder="Mobile"
                  {...register("Mobile", { required: true })}
                />
                <label for="floatingInputValue">
                  Mobile<span className="mandatory">*</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3 mx-3 form-floating">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="floatingInputValue"
                  placeholder="Address Line 1"
                  {...register("AddressLine1", { required: true })}
                />
                <label for="floatingInputValue">
                  Address Line 1<span className="mandatory">*</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-2 form-floating">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="floatingInputValue"
                  placeholder="Address Line 2"
                  {...register("AddressLine2")}
                />
                <label for="floatingInputValue">Address Line 2</label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="d-flex flex-row my-2">
              <div className="col-md-3 form-floating">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="floatingInputValue"
                  placeholder="City"
                  {...register("City", { required: true })}
                />
                <label for="floatingInputValue">
                  City<span className="mandatory">*</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3 mx-3 form-floating">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="floatingInputValue"
                  placeholder="State"
                  {...register("State", { required: true })}
                />
                <label for="floatingInputValue">
                  State<span className="mandatory">*</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-2 form-floating">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="floatingInputValue"
                  placeholder="Country"
                  {...register("Country", { required: true })}
                />
                <label for="floatingInputValue">
                  Country<span className="mandatory">*</span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="d-flex flex-row my-2">
              <div className="col-md-3 form-floating">
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="floatingInputValue"
                  placeholder="ZipCode"
                  {...register("Zipcode", { required: true })}
                />
                <label for="floatingInputValue">
                  ZipCode<span className="mandatory">*</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3 mx-3 form-floating">
                <select
                  className="form-select"
                  aria-label="Default select example"
                  {...register("Availability", { required: true })}
                >
                  <option value="">All</option>
                  <option
                    value="active"
                    selected={
                      candidateDetails?.results?.Availability === "active"
                        ? "selected"
                        : ""
                    }
                  >
                    Active
                  </option>
                  <option
                    value="Inactive"
                    selected={
                      candidateDetails?.results?.Availability === "Inactive"
                        ? "selected"
                        : ""
                    }
                  >
                    In Active
                  </option>
                </select>
                <label for="floatingInputValue">
                  Availability<span className="mandatory">*</span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="job-prefer">Job Type preferred</div>

            <div className="d-flex flex-row my-2">
              <div className="col-md-3 form-floating">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="floatingInputValue"
                  placeholder="Role"
                  {...register("Role")}
                />
                <label for="floatingInputValue">Role</label>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3 mx-3 form-floating">
                <select
                  className="form-select"
                  aria-label="Default select example"
                  {...register("Jobtype")}
                  defaultValue={candidateDetails?.results?.Jobtype}
                >
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <option
                    value="full time"
                    selected={
                      candidateDetails?.results?.Jobtype === "full time"
                        ? "selected"
                        : ""
                    }
                  >
                    Full Time
                  </option>
                  <option
                    value="part time"
                    selected={
                      candidateDetails?.results?.Jobtype === "part time"
                        ? "selected"
                        : ""
                    }
                  >
                    Part Time
                  </option>
                </select>
                <label for="floatingInputValue">Job Type</label>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3 form-floating">
                <input
                  type="date"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="floatingInputValue"
                  {...register("StartdateofExclusivity")}
                />
                <label for="floatingInputValue">
                  Start date for Exclusivity<span className="mandatory">*</span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="education-details">Education & Experience</div>

            <div className="d-flex flex-row my-2">
              <div className="col-md-3 form-floating">
                <select
                  className="form-select"
                  aria-label="Default select example"
                  {...register("Qualification")}
                >
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <option
                    value="post graduate"
                    selected={
                      candidateDetails?.results?.Qualification ===
                      "post graduate"
                        ? "selected"
                        : ""
                    }
                  >
                    Post Graduate
                  </option>
                  <option
                    value="graduate"
                    selected={
                      candidateDetails?.results?.Qualification === "graduate"
                        ? "selected"
                        : ""
                    }
                  >
                    Graduate
                  </option>
                </select>
                <label for="floatingInputValue">Qualification</label>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3 mx-3 form-floating">
                <select
                  className="form-select"
                  aria-label="Default select example"
                  {...register("Experience")}
                >
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <option
                    value="2-3 years"
                    selected={
                      candidateDetails?.results?.Experience === "2-3 years"
                        ? "selected"
                        : ""
                    }
                  >
                    2-3 years
                  </option>
                  <option
                    value="3-4 years"
                    selected={
                      candidateDetails?.results?.Experience === "3-4 years"
                        ? "selected"
                        : ""
                    }
                  >
                    3-4 years
                  </option>
                </select>
                <label for="floatingInputValue">Experience</label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="my-2">
              <div className="notes">Notes</div>
              <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                <div className="col-md-4 type-area">
                  <textarea
                    className="form-control"
                    id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
                    rows="5"
                    placeholder="Type here..."
                    {...register("Notes")}
                  ></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            {/* <div className="col-md-6">
              <label className="resume">Upload Resume<img src={plusCircle} alt="..." id="plus-icon"></img></label>
              <span className="resume-upload">Upload Resume</span>
              <img src={plusCircle} alt="..." id="plus-icon"></img>
              <input
                type="file"
                {...register("Upload")}
                onChange={handleChange}
              ></input>
            </div> */}
            <div className="col-md-6">
            <label className="resume">Upload Resume<img src={plusCircle} alt="..." id="plus-icon"></img></label>
            <input
                type="file"
                {...register("Upload")}
                onChange={handleChange}
              ></input>
            </div>

            <div className="format-file">
              <div className="checking-box">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-box" />
              </div>
              <div className="checking-label">
                <label>HSC Formatted</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="my-4">
            <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
              <div className="col-md-3">
                <Link to={"/candidates"}>
                  <button type="button" className="cancel-btn">
                    Cancel
                  </button>
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3">
                <button type="submit" className="saving-button">
                  Save
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

What is the problem in my code please let me know.

Comment: Add your JSX please

Answer (score 0):

One problem that i can think of is that you are adding `{"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}` manually.

```js
const saveCandidate = await axios.post(`${url}/hhc/createCandidate`, data, {headers:{"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}});
```

You should not do that as it could strip out the important boundary value that is auto generated each time both in the header and in the payload. to properly parse the payload for knowing when a file ends.

```js
const fd = new FormData()
fd.set('x', new Blob([123]))

const res = new Response(fd)
console.log(res.headers.get('content-type'))
res.text().then(console.log)
```

So you should just be doing

```js
const saveCandidate = await axios.post(`${url}/hhc/createCandidate`, data);
```

Not b/c it's any of my business but i think you should be

- using fetch instead of axios...
- use [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute instead
- Have a name field on all input elements

  - Then use `fd = new FormData(formElement)` instead of manually adding each field

Comment: const saveCandidate = await axios.post(`${url}/hhc/createCandidate`, data);
Not working, Can you please let me know any possible way

Comment: it's a little tuff without a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or something. you can log the formdata entries using `console.log([...fd])` to inspect what entries it includes to see if there are any files there or not.